# Shopify Liquid - What would be the equivalent of this JS code in liquid?

Tags: shopify, shopify-liquid

Liquid seems to be very restrictive and I am not really able to figure out how to get the liquid equivalent of the below JS code:

```js
const allIngredients = {
   vitamin_c: {
     title: "Vitamin C",
     description: "Some text here",
   },
   vitamin_k: {
     title: "Vitamin K",
     description: "Some text here",
   }
}

const productIngredients = ["vitamin_k"]

productIngredients.map(ingredient => {
  console.log(allIngredients[ingredient])
});
```

**Update:**

I have multiple products and each product comprises of multiple ingredients. These ingredients are stored in `product.Ingredients`.

Structure:

```
{
  "vitamin_c" => { 
    "ingredient_title" => "Vitamin C",
    "ingredient_description" => "Some text here"
  },
  "vitamin_k" => { 
    "ingredient_title" => "Vitamin K",
    "ingredient_description" => "Some text here"
  },
  ...
}
```

In the product metafield, I am adding the keys of the above json i.e. `vitamin_c` and `vitamin_k`.

Now what I want to do is to map the metafield values with the `product.Ingredients` json and print the ingredient_title and the ingredient_description on my page.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The difference is that you don't really have objects in liquid. I mean you cannot create ones by yourself. There are some objects served by Shopify but it will be easier for you to think about them like they are arrays. Maybe you can share what you are trying to accomplish using liquid and what have you tried already? It will be easier to write a code for that particular case

Comment: Thanks, where does `product.Ingredients` come from? I can't find it anywhere in the docs.

Comment: It is a custom object that I created in the `en.default.json` file

Comment: Just use Javascript. You store the JSON in a Metafield. Render that FROM Liquid into JS. Then render that into DOM. You do not use Liquid like JS.

Comment: Exactly what I ended up doing. Thanks for the help though.